# Can delta-star conversions be used to resolve any circuit of resistors into series and parallel combinations of resistors?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Can [delta-star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) conversions be used to resolve any circuit of resistors into series and parallel combinations of resistors? I mean to say that if we do not utilize any other techniques like merging points with the same potential and so on, can we reduce any circuit to a simple one where all resistances are in some combination of parallel and series connections?

Comment: Hint: think about *non-planar circuits*.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform): *Every two-terminal network represented by a planar graph can be reduced to a single equivalent resistor by a sequence of series, parallel, $Y$-$\Delta$, and $\Delta$-$Y$ transformations. However, there are non-planar networks that cannot be simplified using these transformations, such as a regular square grid wrapped around a torus, or any member of the Petersen family.*

Comment: Somebody: "does every graph ..." - Petersen graph: "No."